# Can we reopen my question, so it can get a good answer?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-closed

I wrote a question: [Destructuring an optionally chained object, to get the ...rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62760672/1075247) which felt like a technical problem, but I was only given 'Try this instead' answers. Which while accurate is unsatisfying.

However I then go this answer:

> It's not. These are two separate concerns; the RHS resolves to either some.optional.chaining or undefined, and the latter definitely can't be destructured (also the former maybe can't be).

From jonrsharpe,

Which shows me how to approach this from an adaptive solution perspective. It gives me a why, which is more satisfying a conclusion.

Comment: Answers aside, I have no idea why that question was closed in the first place, it isn't remotely opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I've cast the final re-open vote that it needed.

Now, you can suggest that user write their answer…